# Adding a Sale Price to Woocommerce Product creates spacing issue

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using:

- WordPress version 4.7.1
- Woocommerce version 2.6.12
- The Retailer Theme version 2.1

When I add a Sale Price to a product the products below that particular item get pushed over. As seen here:

http://st-tropezhome.com/shop/product-category/decor/vases/

You can see I've added a Sale Price to the product "Vase Atacama 16″" and this causes the products in the row below to be pushed over to the right.

I've inspected these elements and am not seeing anything strange in the CSS that would cause this spacing issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the `line-height` on the `del` element which contains the old price works for me:

```
.price del {
    line-height: 1;
}
```

Comment: I think this is only a partial solution. The theme seems to be using `nth-child()` to tell the rows when to break so that the number of items per row changes as the screen size changes. Nice in theory, however, the theme throws this off by adding an `<a>` as the first item in the `<ul class="products">` list, which throws off the nth child count. If you can remove this `<a>` the rows should resize as designed.